Base64 image decode to JPEG issue: binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
I have a data set with three columns of encoded Base64 images (small, medium, normal sized) that i need to decode and write the output filename into a XLS file column; data sample here.
I got the following script based on this thread I found here to bulk decode the base64 into images after inputting them into a text file. TXT samples here.
import fileinput
import base64

for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(), 1):
    with open('imagen{0:04}.jpg'.format(index), 'wb') as jpg:
       line = line.strip()
       jpg.write(base64.b64decode(line))

I can decode the small, and medium images set with no problems, but the normal sized image outputs this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\64IMGDECODER\DECODER2.py", line 7, in <module>
    jpg.write(base64.b64decode(line))
  File "C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

Is there a way to fix this incorrect padding binascii error, force the output or re-pad, or is the data from the Excel data file cooked?, I haven't found a workaround it.

Update: I was able to bypass the binasciii padding error using:
import fileinput
import base64
import binascii

for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(), 1):
    with open('imagen{0:04}.png'.format(index), 'wb') as png:
       line = line.strip()
       try:
         decoded = base64.b64decode(line + '====')
       except binascii.Error:
         decoded = base64.b64decode(line[0:-1] + '====')
       png.write(decoded)

As stated in the thread I used for reference, also this one helped a lot, but now the output of the decode are corrupt images.
So, I'm guessing the original data in the XLS was bad after all. I might have to scrape that all over again.
Image output faulty:


Workaround: try decoding with 7-Zip, https://7-zip.org/ : since 2019, it handles Base64: https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt.

how would it be the procedure? i tried making a file with the base64 code in, and name it with b64 extension, i really havent found more documentation about that

so, i was able to process all the data sets, including the big images, but as commented in the edit of the posts, the images comes out corrupted, i guess the data sets on the excel are actually bad so thats a issue for another question i think hahah.. :')
